# cant load css and javascript in codeigniter 3.0.4

Tags: javascript, html, css, codeigniter

i cant load my css and js in the view file i already added them in the folder and already set my base url  these code however is working with a project i did on a lower version of codeigniter . what seems to be wrong?
my view:

```
 <link href="<?php echo base_url()?>js/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />



    </br></br>
            <div class="panel panel-primary" style=" width: 1050px; border-radius: 0">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="border-radius: 0 ">user List    <button  data-toggle="tooltip"   data-placement="bottom" title="Print Customer Order" style="border-radius: 0px;"type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
                                        <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'admin/printlist/'; ?>">
                                                   Print List
                                                      </a>
                                            </button> </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" style="border-radius: 0 ">  

                        <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered" >  
                            <thead>  

                                <tr>  

                                     <th>Surname</th> 
                                    <th>Name </th>  
                                    <th>Age</th>  
                                    <th>School</th>  
                                   <th>Course</th>  
                                    <th>Email</th>  

                                </tr>  
                            </thead>  
                            <tbody>  


                               <?php foreach ($user as $users): ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $users->surname; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $users->name; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $users->age; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $users->school; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $users->course; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $users->email; ?></td>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </tbody>  
                        </table>  
                               </div>

                    </div>



                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

            <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
            <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#myTable').dataTable({
                        "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]]
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Are you loading the CSS and JS in the `<head>` of your page?

Comment: <?php echo base_url()?> change base_url to site_url if you found index.php in your url.

Comment: At the end of `<?php echo base_url()?>` is maybe a `/` missing? You can see this in de developer console when you hit the F12 key in your browser.

Comment: checked all your comments and they are all fine

Comment: @Christian, do you get specific errors?

Answer (score 2):

I have done some research and i found that the default location for css files is the same level as the application in Codigniter. I.E:

```
/css
/application
```

Check this first if that's your case. You can fix this with some simple `../` in front of the echo.

Another thing I noticed is, your CSS file is located in a js folder (`js/dataTables/`)? Maybe this is a fast copy/paste fault?

Answer (score 2):

Put CSS and JS folder in your project folder root(Application level).

I have created 'assets' folder in my project and put css and js folder in it. It's working fine.

assets/js/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.js">

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake
Replace `<?php echo base_url()?>` to `<?php echo base_url(); ?>`